# How to send current of line of code to terminal input in gedit 2013?

Tags: command-line, gedit

I just switched to ubuntu.  I want to use  R and I am using gedit to write R script. When I was using Mac, I was able to use run a R script line by line. However, I have no idea how to do this now in gedit.

I notice someone said it was impossible to do so [How can I send current line in gedit to terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68986/how-can-i-send-current-line-in-gedit-to-terminal), but that was 2 years ago. And recently, I saw people doing it on youtube.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4jJDkcEs5yw

Comment: I donot know about gedit but take a look at http://www.geany.org/. It has support for building custom commands as well as http://www.geany.org/manual/#sending-text-through-custom-commands

Comment: What were you using on OSX to edit & execute scripts? `gedit` is mostly just an editor, so it might not be the tool you're looking for.

Comment: I was able to do it with R the program. But now in Ubuntu, I have to work with R within the terminal

Answer (score 2):

The youtube video you reference appears to point to a [blog post](http://programlama.wordpress.com/2013/07/27/run-command-line-or-selected-text-on-a-previous-window-gedit-external-tool/) that explains how to do it. The post isn't in English, but it's well written, so you can infer the steps to take. I just tried it out and it works for me just like the video illustrates. So that I'm not just posting the link, here are abbreviated instructions:

1. install the needed packages: `apt-get install gedit-plugins xdotool`
2. In gedit, visit the Tools->Manage External Tools menu, and create two new tools. I called mine "Send Line to Previous Window" and "Send Selection to Previous Window." The code for both is the same, see below. Configure each command as below

   - For **"Send line..."**

     - Shortcut: *Alt+L*
     - Save: *Nothing*
     - Input: *Current Line*
     - Output: *Nothing*
     - Applicability: *All documents / All Language*s
   - For **"Send selection..."**

     - Shortcut: *Alt+B*
     - Save: *Nothing*
     - Input: *Current Selection*
     - Output: *Nothing*
     - Applicability: *All documents / All Languages*

The Code

```
#!/bin/sh

read line
xdotool key alt+Tab
xdotool sleep 0.2
xdotool type "$line"
xdotool key Return
xdotool key alt+Tab
```

Note, the example code used `cat - > /tmp/runprev_meh.txt; line=$(cat /tmp/runprev_meh.txt)` instead of `read line`, but I think it's cleaner and doesn't introduce anyproblems.

Comment: how come you have 2 identical shortcut key for "send current line" and "send current selection" ? My gedit doesnt allow me to do so. How can I have have 2 identical shortcut for 2 different external tools?

Comment: Oops. Copy/paste error. Those should be different. I think I use Alt+L and Alt+B.

Answer (score 0):

A good way of doing this is to use external tools in gedit.

Do the following:
gedit -> Edit -> Preferences -> Plugins -> Check External Tools

Then:
gedit -> Tools -> Manage External Tools

Here:
Add a tool by clicking on the '+' button.

Name: Run line
Shortcut Key: Alt+L (or whatever you are comfortable with)
Save: Nothing
Input: Current Line
Output: Display in bottom pane

Put this code in the **Edit** section:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys
import commands

line = sys.stdin.read()
print commands.getoutput(line)
```

Name: Run select
Shortcut Key: Alt+B (or whatever you are comfortable with)
Save: Nothing
Input: Current selection
Output: Display in bottom pane

Put this code in the **Edit** section:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys
import commands

line = sys.stdin.read().replace("\r","")
print commands.getoutput(line)
```